# How do you position a MudBlazor Dialog using a custom DialogPosition?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Given a MudBlazor MudDialog component with a Position set to DialogPosition.Custom, the dialog will appear absolutely positioned to the top left hand corner of the viewport.

```
@{
   var dialogOptions = new DialogOptions
   {
     Position = DialogPosition.Custom,
   };
}
<MudDialog Options="@dialogOptions" Class="custom-dialog">
  <DialogContent>
    Hello World.
  </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
```

There isn't a position property in the options. The documentation doesn't reference custom positioning at all.

Once the component has rendered, the CSS class `.custom-dialog` isn't applied to the dialog parent, but a static div a few levels down the tree, so positional styles cannot be applied to it.

Is there a way to set the custom position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set it as `DialogPostion.Custom` it applies the `.mud-dialog-custom` class to the dialog parent.

It's an undefined class so I believe it was designed to be overridden. So you simply use that class to apply your custom position.

e.g.

```
<style>
    .mud-dialog-custom{
        display: grid;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        justify-items: end;
    }
</style>

<MudDialog>
  <DialogContent>
    Hello World.
  </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
```

[TryMudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cawdOLmJpywPTTyU)

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this yet but just wanted to say thanks. My only query is what to do if there are multiple custom dialogs on the page, but I'll do some testing.

Comment: @NandoLorris have a look at the snippet, each overridden `.mud-dialog-custom` is in it's own dialog component. So you can have multiple different styled custom dialogs in a single page and their custom styles will be in their own component.